# Refresh button on Browser

Tags: php, html

I have a simple coding problem. I try to create a page with a textbox and a share button.

When the user clicks the share button the text in the textbox get inserted as string into the database table named "posts".

I use the following code.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['share']))
    {
            $status = $_POST['status'];
            $res = mysql_query("insert into `posts`(postid,username,post,pointscollected) values('','$username','$status','')");
            if($res)
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Posted successfully')</script>";
            else
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('some error')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
            <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
            Status : <input type = "text" name ="status">
            <input type = "submit" name ="share">
            </form>
        <?php
    }
```

This solution works fine but there is a **problem when the user refreshes the page**. The browser will show a message window asking for resend the information, which will submit the post to the table again. Then the **same entry is in the table twice**.

I want the **user to stay on the same page** after submitting. But a page refresh should not show the message window or send the information again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Redirect the user after he shares, use redirect

```
header('Location: whatever.php');
exit;
```

Use this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['share'])) {
      $status = $_POST['status'];
      $res = mysql_query("insert into `posts`(postid,username,post,pointscollected) values('','$username','$status','')");
      if($res) {
      ?>
          <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Posted successfully')</script>
      <?php              
          header('Location: whatever.php');
          exit;
        } else {
         ?>
          <script type='text/javascript'>alert('some error')</script>
       <?php
          header('Location: whatever.php');
          exit;
         }
    }
 ?>
```

And btw better don't alert the users using javascript

**AND DO USE BRACES AROUND IF ELSE**

P.S : You Can Also Redirect An User Using JavaScript `window.location`

[**Header Reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Would be better if `header(...);` is placed before output. While it may work in its current form, it may as well break if buffers get flushed before `header(...);`. This is going to happen for example when someone adds some more lines inside `<script/>` or simply if *output_buffering* is either disabled or value is near to disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "redirect-after-post": After you received the post request and did something useful with it, you redirect the user (usually) back to theire own post, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing redirect just after your logic saving the post is done.

```
            header("location: $my_page");
            exit();
```

Set variable $your_page with the name of page which contains your code
$my_page = 'yourpage.php';

This should work:

```
$my_page = 'your_page.php'
if(isset($_POST['share']))
{
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $res = mysql_query("insert into `posts`(postid,username,post,pointscollected) values('','$username','$status','')");
        if($res)
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Posted successfully')</script>";
            header("location: $my_page");
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('some error')</script>";
            header("location: $my_page");
            exit();
        }
}
```

Comment: No need of declaring a variable for that

Answer (score 0):

Right after you have finished inserting your query and everything, change to another page using:

```
<?php
header('Location: /path/to/yourotherpage.php');
exit();
?>
```

What this does, is it is a redirect to another page, which removes all POST data from the browser's 'memory' of the page.

On that page, you write something like 'Your stuff has been submitted and recorded', whatever you want, your choice.

If your user refreshes on that page, nothing will be inserted at all.

That should work.